# How to show "first time hint style" animation in flutter listview tile as sliding from right to left?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the user to see the listTile slide a bit to reveal the actions and buttons put behind it, so that user knows the hidden features like 'slide to delete'

Comment: Just initiate the animation, using animatedBuilder and animationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial. You can overlay an animation when a user use your app first time.

https://pub.dev/packages/tuxin_tutorial_overlay